# How to set retrofit parameters properly

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-developer-api, rx-java2

I'm trying to create Weather app using Retrofit 2 and now I struggle to set the call properly.

Here's the URL that is working:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=MY_API_KEY
```

So, I've got my API key and BASE URL is:http://api.openweathermap.org .. This is the method in my Retrofit service:

```
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather?q={city}/&APPID={api}")
    Observable<WeatherResponse> getWeather(@Path("city") String city, @Path("api") String api);
```

And the error I get is:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "q={city}/&APPID={api}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

So I tried like this:

```
@GET("/data/2.5/weather?{city}/&APPID={api}")
Observable<WeatherResponse> getWeather(@Query("city") String city, @Path("api") String api);
```

And I get the same error... Anyone knows what's the deal here, what's wrong with my url?

Answer (score 8):

Do it this way:

```
@GET("/data/2.5/weather")
Observable<WeatherResponse> getWeather(@Query("q") String city, @Query("APPID") String api);
```

There is no need to manually put parameter values in Retrofit - you have to only tell it what are parameters names

Comment: Now I get this error :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A Path parameter must not come after a Query.  ...You know why can't Path come after Query?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - there should be only Query annotations in you request. Path is used when you want to insert parameter in the middle of requests, e.g some id: `/get/users/1/info` - there 1 is id, and in Retrofit will be used Path("id") : `/get/users/{id}/info`

Comment: man you saved my weekend with the @Path Argument to insert requests in the middle